# Codesigning Frameworks in OSX Mac App Store App

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, frameworks, code-signing

I am trying to upload my OSX App the the Mac App Store. I keep getting an email due to "Invalid Binary". The email mentions "Invalid Signature - The main app bundle App Name at path App Name.app has following signing error(s): --"

It then lists the Frameworks that I am using in my app including Parse.com.
How can I fix this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it;

- Enter to the build settings of your target
- Fing the line "Other Code Signing Flags
- Enter **--deep** value to the release parameter
- Close XCode
- Enter to the derived data folder on your Mac and delete the old derived data (default path is: /Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData)
- Open Xcode and build

If it's not built, try downloading the latest version of the SDKs from Parse and try again.

After the build archive and submit the app again. It should be fine.